# Problems deploying app and database to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have built an asp.net webforms app with a DB which works great locally. I created a new context with an initializer class as they describe [here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer). The DB is nicely seeded with my initial data onto localDB and everything runs beautifully. (Doing code first, no migrations according to the tutorial in the link above).

I have published my app to its online counterpart and everything seems fine until I enter a page which I know contains a context of my DB. At this point the database should be seeded as it successfully does locally however I just receive a time-out error. I suppose it is not connecting to my DB properly.

What is the proper method of publishing a webforms app and DB together to Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are using Azure App Service (formerly known as Azure Website).

LocalDB is not supported see [Using a LocalDb MDF file on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870996/using-a-localdb-mdf-file-on-azure)

please config your application to use remote database such as SQL Azure.

Comment: Do you do that by just changing the connection string to the remote connection string?

Comment: yes. but depends on where your remote database is. you might need to do some extra configuration on the database end. e.g https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/