# Local database in Azure hosting web application

Tags: azure

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET Core, and currently during the development I am utilizing provided SQL Server LocalDB. Would I be able to deploy it to Azure along with my web application? Would I be able to use it instead of renting Azure SqlServer? This is my little testing application mainly dedicated for studying, so I am trying to save extra bucks.

Comment: I've found the problem is that future deployments will update your database. There might be ways around this, but it is much easier to use SQL Azure because you don't run the risk of losing your data so easily.

Comment: good point, so it is possible and it would work just fine, cool, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use LocalDB and MDF files on Azure unfortunately. You can however use SQL Server Compact. Take a look at [Using a LocalDb MDF file on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870996/using-a-localdb-mdf-file-on-azure) on how that is done.

Comment: Why are you saying LocalDB cannot be installed on Azure? I think you are talking specifically about Web Apps, not Virtual Machines.

Comment: Yes, of course you can use it on VM. You can do lots of crazy stuff on a VM. If you read between the lines though it feels OP is likely using app services.