# Azure Cloud webapp&Database setup issue

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, localdb

I am new at this, and for a class for college I need to setup a cloud web app with azure. Needless to say, I have no idea what I am doing, and and only following the instructions shown at this guide from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app.

I have followed all the steps perfectly (I think), but have hit an issue with step 4 of generating a database schema. its telling me to run ./migrate through ssh, which I did, and it only gives me a bunch of text that I definitely don't understand, and then at the end it says in red: "LocalDB is not supported on this platform."

I found a post on github saying that LocalDB is not supported on Linux, which is the OS i'm using. I also found another saying that you cant really change the OS. Is there a way to get this working? I found a few things in other posts mentioning other options, like this one: [How to connect a localdb from Visual Studio to the published Azure web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060346/how-to-connect-a-localdb-from-visual-studio-to-the-published-azure-web-app/42061693#42061693).

I dont really know what to do from here and could use some help.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy web app with database to azure?

Comment: Are you trying to use redis?

Comment: Pls check the 7 8 9 steps in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app#3-deploy-sample-code) to  make sure you added all the required commands and other configurations. We already created Azure sql database and Azure cache for redis, so that we need to replace and add some configurations in the sample code. The error message you are facing is pointing to an error which you are still using local database but not the one we created. So that make sure we already changed the configurations for database resource.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned code from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app) which was provided by you.

While creating a web app + database, I chose SQLAzure as the engine and selected "No" for adding Azure Cache for Redis, as shown below.

[image]

After clicking the "Review + Create" button, I was prompted to the screen below, where I copied the username and password.

[image]

After successfully creating a web app in Azure, I opened the cloned project on my local machine and changed the connection string in appsettings.json.

```
   "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnection": "Server=tcp:<YourServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<yourDataBaseName>-database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<UserID>;Password=<Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication="
  }
```

**appsettings.json**:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnection": "Server=tcp:<YourServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=kasampledbapp-database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<UserID>;Password=<Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication="
  }
}
```

For migration purposes, I deleted the old migration file and ran the following command in the Package Manager Console.

```
enable-migrations

add-migration InitialCreate

update-database
```

After that, go to your Database server in the Azure portal and add your client address as shown below.

[image]

**Local Output**:

[image]

To publish, right-click on the project name and select the "Publish" option, as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the image below, I selected my web app in Azure.

[image]

I successfully published my web app to Azure, as shown below.

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]