# .NET Deployment to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

So I've finally deployed to Azure, I've got my application live though its not passing my databases over and i get the error at the bottom.

I use Local DB and have SQL Server express installed. How do i publish my database to Azure with it? I've changed my datasource connection string to something generic:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I found a post about SQL Server compact, is this the best way?

I use code first migrations which I read is easiest just really need some direction on what is best as I'm clueless!

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +209
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +426
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +86
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +164
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +151
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
```

It goes on but I don't think anymore is relevant!

Comment: probably better to use Azure SQL, as it is PaaS service

Comment: SQLite can be a good choice if you want your database embedded with your app. You can't use LocalDB that way in Azure unless you are using your own VM.

Comment: What did you deploy to Azure? Did you deploy to an Azure VM or a PaaS offering?

Comment: @virusstorm i believe PaaS? i just did right click and publish onto a web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and the comments, I believe you published you application to an Azure PaaS solution. The issue you are running into is Azure App Services do not let you use LocalDB. You will need to use Azure SQL Databases for your application. Without knowing more about how you created and use your database, I can't say for certain what will be the best way to fix your problem. You may need to use a SQL Server database project and DACPAC to deploy your database or you may simply need to provision an Azure SQL Database and grant your App Services access to it.

Below are links that should help get you pointed in the right direction.

[Using a LocalDb MDF file on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870996/using-a-localdb-mdf-file-on-azure)

[Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)

Comment: Thanks for your help seems like a great place to start :) have been looking into SQL server compact since ive been researching is this at all viable? I read when I created an Azure SQL database that its not good for scalability?

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that Azure SQL Database does not scale, but I know for a fact it does. There are many ways to scale it, provided you understand what your requirements are for scaling. I don't believe SQL Compact will work either, but more importantly, it is not supported to run Azure App Services. So I wouldn't recommend trying to use it on any of the PaaS offerings.

Comment: ahh that's great then will look into that! the first post you linked is actually the one i was using and the best answer suggested SQL compact, but i would rather azure if its scalable. So my understanding is i have to create a transform file for my webconfig to use my sql azure, upload my mdf to sql azure and then it should work publishing the app?

Comment: I'm not sure how you created your MDF file, but you can't upload it to Azure directly. Typically, you would use SQL Server database projects to deploy to Azure or have the database provisioned a head of time and simply use EF code first to deploy the database.